# Alterar um LookUpCombobox de acordo com outro

Tags: delphi

Eu gostaria de fazer um `LookUpCombobox` em Delphi que se comportasse da seguinte maneira:

- Quando o usuário clicasse escolhendo naturalidade: Brasileira ou Brasileira, Nascido no Exterior ou Naturalizado, outro `LookUpCombobox` fosse automaticamente selecionado como o pais Brasil e ficasse indisponível para alteração.
- Quando o usuário selecionasse Estrangeiro, o outro `LookUpCombobox` ficaria em branco e o usuário teria a opção de escolher o país, mas não pudesse escolher Brasil.

Quando eu clico em Post para salvar os valores, o campo Pais fica em branco e não salva quando é Brasil. Eu fiz um `showmessage()` na variável e ela retorna o código correto do país que é 76.

Segue o código:

```
procedure TformCadastroEstudantes.DBLookupComboBoxNacionalidadeCloseUp(
  Sender: TObject);
  var nacionalidade : Integer;
  var pais :   Integer;
  var enabled : Boolean;

  begin

    nacionalidade := DBLookupComboBoxNacionalidade.KeyValue;
    pais := DBLookupComboBoxPais.KeyValue;
    enabled := True;

    AtualizaPaises(nacionalidade, pais, enabled);

    DBLookupComboBoxPais.KeyValue := pais;
    DBLookupComboBoxPais.Enabled  := enabled;
  end;
```

Segue o código do procedimento:

```
procedure AtualizaPaises(var nacionalidade : Integer; var pais: Integer; var enabled : Boolean);

begin

     if ((nacionalidade = 1) OR (nacionalidade = 2)) then
     begin
       pais := 76;
       enabled := False;

       with dm.sqlPaises do
       begin
         Close;
         SQL.Clear;
         SQL.Add('select * from PAISES');
         SQL.Add('where CODIGO_PAIS like ''76''');
         SQL.Add('order by NOME_PAIS');
         Open;
       end;

     end

    else
    begin
       pais := 0;
       enabled := True;

       with dm.sqlPaises do
        begin
          Close;
          SQL.Clear;
          SQL.Add('select * from PAISES');
          SQL.Add('where CODIGO_PAIS not like ''76''');
          SQL.Add('order by NOME_PAIS');
          Open;
        end;
    end;
 end;
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta: você cita "naturalidade: cidade e estado onde nasceu", mas deseja ter dois LookupComboBox para selecionar o País? Ou você escreveu por engano "naturalidade"?

Comment: @Diego Felipe - Na verdade é nacionalidade

Comment: @prmas - Na verdade é nacionalidade - Primeiro tenho que saber se é Brasileiro ou Naturalizado, caso positivo somente Brasil como pais deve ser permitido, não podendo alterar. Se estrangeiro, todos menos o Brasil pode ser permitido.

Comment: acho que não entendi, tente setar a propriedade KeyValue do outro LookUpCombobox para o valor desejado

Answer (score 1):

nunca trabalhei com o lookupcombobox mas tente realizar da seguinte forma.

No evento onexit da primeira combo faça a seguinte validação

```
if DBLookupComboBox1.listField = 'Brasileira' then
   begin
      DBLookupComboBox2.enabled := False;
      DBLookupComboBox2.listfieldIndex := Valor Do Pais;  // provavelmente deve ser o id do mesmo   
   end
else 
   begin
      DBLookupComboBox2.enabled := True;
      DBLookupComboBox2.listFieldIndex := 0;
   end;
```

Trabalho geralmente com a combobox mesmo, onde preencho a mesma em tempo de execução juntamente com FireDac onde acaba deixando a aplicação ate mais rápida do que dessa forma utilizando com componentes DB.

Porem a ideia é a mesma, localizar o index para o registro que você deseja para uma determinada ação realizada dentro do sistema.